# Usage of the phrase している

Tags: grammar, usage

While I was working on 日本語総まとめ N3 文法, I came across the following.

ここの砂は星みたいな形**をしている**.

Now I know that this translates to "The sand here in this area are star-shaped."

What I don't understand here is the usage of the bold-faced phrase をしている. Can someone please help me with this? Problem is the usage (in what sort of occasions specifically).

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2289/9831

Comment: Thank you @Chocolate for the pointer... That solved my problem.